# finding q1 and q3 using median() in a python program of an unsorted number list without NumPy, pandas or other packages

Tags: python, math

I'm having some trouble writing a small piece of code for school. We're supposed to find the lower and upper quartile for a list of numbers. I've already written the following median() function:

```
def median(lst):

sorted_list = sorted(lst)
list_len = len(lst)
data = (len(lst) - 1) // 2

if list_len % 2:
    return float(sorted_list[data])
else:
    return (sorted_list[data] + sorted_list[data + 1]) / 2.0
```

Using this function I'm supposed to find the lower and upper quartile of some short lists of numbers.

Problem is I have no idea how to go at this, my python skills are still beginner and maths isn't my best side. Can someone help me out?

Comment: `sorted_list[list_len//4]` for the first quartile?

Comment: `def q1(lst):
    sorted_list = sorted(lst)
    list_len = len(lst)
    return float(sorted_list[list_len // 4])`

Error: q1([4, 2, 5, 8, 6]) gives 4.0 instead of 3.0

Comment: When you say you want the upper and lower quartiles, do you mean the median of those quartiles or a list of number that make up that quartile?

Comment: @JCaesar Neither. The lower [quartile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) is the value v such that 25% of the data is lower than v and 75% of the data is higher than v.

Comment: @VincentHolthaus What definitions or properties of the quartiles do you know? Have you heard something like "the lower quartile is the median of the first half of the data"?

Comment: Of course, you should make amends for when the amount data isn't an exact multiple of four (or rather, a multiple of four + 1), just as you did for the median calculation (which has different paths for when the amount of data is divisible by two, and when not). My suggestion provides just a starting point.

Comment: NB: `np.percentile([4, 2, 5, 8, 6], 25)` yields 4, not 3, in contrast to your claim. Why do you claim it is 3?

Comment: @9769953 I don't claim it, my school provides a testing framework that tests random lists. This is the error the framework gives me.

Comment: @Stef I really just have to find the first and third quartiles of a list, so from [4, 2, 6, 3, 8] I need 4 and 2. (and 3 and 8 in another function)

Comment: @VincentHolthaus Yes. I've understood your problem. But this looks like homework. Presumably you have received some course material before being given the homework. Presumably you were given a definition of quartile. And perhaps a few properties of quartiles, or different ways to compute a quartile. Could you list these definitions and properties, and see if one of them is not, per chance, exactly the tool you need to solve this problem?